# What would be authorization endpoint for oauth in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, api, rest-api, oauth

I am trying to build an api that delivers magento resources to a third party  and for that I am using oauth for authentication purpose. On the third-party side the application asks for a authorization endpoint however, in magento dev-docs I was only able to find request token and access token endpoints.In magento 1 it used to be

> 'http://magentohost/oauth/authorize'

How would I go about providing authorization endpoint. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be

```
POST /oauth/token/request
```

For more details refer to http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html